# Multithreading calculations in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I want to create a script to calculate numbers in multiple threads. Each thread will calculate the powers of 2 but the first thread must start calculating from 2, the second from 4, and the third from 8, printing some text in-between.

Example:

```
Im a thread and these are my results
2
4
8
Im a thread and these are my results
4
8
16
Im a thread and these are my results
8
16
32
```

My fail code:

```
def loopa(s)
    3.times do
        puts s
        s=s**2
    end
end
threads=[]
num=2
until num == 8 do
    threads << Thread.new{ loopa(num) }
    num=num**2
end
threads.each { |x| puts "Im a thread and these are my results" ; x.join }
```

My fail results:

```
Im a thread and these are my results
8
64
4096
8
64
4096
8
64
4096
Im a thread and these are my results
Im a thread and these are my results
```

Comment: I think you want plain old multiplication (`*`), rather than the exponentiation (`**`) you've got now.

Comment: Must the output lines be ordered in exactly the same way as your expected "Example" section? If so, then the code will need a major restructuring.

Comment: Do you have to use threads? The problem you're trying to solve does not seem to require them.

Comment: You say you want powers of two, but in the expected example, you have multiples of two, and in the code and the result, you have second powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read the **"Threads and Processes"** chapter Pragmatic Programmer's ruby book. Here's an [old version](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) online. The section called "**Creating Ruby Threads**" is especially relevant to your question.

To fix the problem, you need to change your `Thread.new` line to this:

```
threads << Thread.new(num){|n| loopa(n) }
```

Your version doesn't work because `num` is shared between threads, and may be changed by another thread. By passing the variable via a block, the block variable is no longer shared.

**More Info**

Also, there's an error in your math.
Output values will be:

```
Thread 1: 2 4 16
Thread 2: 4 16 256
Thread 3: 6 36 1296
```

"8" is never reached because the `until` condition quits as soon as it sees "8".

If you want clearer output, use this as the body of `loopa`:

```
3.times do
    print "#{Thread.current}: #{s}\n"
    s=s**2
end
```

This lets you distinguish the 3 threads. Note that it's better to use a `print` command with a newline-terminated string versus using `puts` without a newline, because the latter prints the newline as a separate instruction, which may be interrupted by another thread.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. Read what you write. Firstly you run 3 threads that are async so output will be in various of combinations of threads output. Then you write 'Im a thread and these are my results' and join each thread. Also remember that Ruby has only references. So if you pass `num` to thread and then change it it will change in all threads. To avoid it write:

```
threads = (1..3).map do |i|
  puts "I'm starting thread no #{i}"
  Thread.new { loopa(2**i) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, to be honest I did the printing line "Im a thread and these are my results" cause I wanted a readable,understandable output.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the need to post a mathematically correct version:

```
def loopa(s)
  3.times do
      print "#{Thread.current}: #{s}\n"
      s *= 2
  end
end

threads=[]
num=2
while num <= 8 do
    threads << Thread.new(num){|n| loopa(n) }
    num *= 2
end

threads.each { |x| print "Im a thread and these are my results\n" ; x.join }
```

**Bonus 1: threadless solution (naive)**

```
power = 1
workers = 3
iterations = 3

(power ... power + workers).each do |pow|
  worker_pow = 2 ** pow
  puts "I'm a worker and these are my results"
  iterations.times do |inum|
    puts worker_pow
    worker_pow *= 2
  end
end
```

**Bonus 2: threadless solution (cached)**

```
power = 1
workers = 3
iterations = 3

cache_size = workers + iterations - 1
# generate all the values upfront
cache = []
(power ... power+cache_size).each do |i|
  cache << 2**i
end

workers.times do |wnum|
  puts "I'm a worker and these are my results"
  # use a sliding-window to grab the part of the cache we want
  puts cache[wnum,3]
end
```